# Count the number of common users in multiple tables

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have 4 tables as shown below

[image]

I basically want to get how many users from table1 are in tables 2, 3 and 4. Similarly for table2 I want to get how many users are present in table 1, 3 and 4. and same for tables 3 and 4

Basically all the possible combinations. The final result I want is something as below

[image]

One of the way I am trying to solve is by doing a `left-join` of `table1` with other tables to followed by `count` to get first row of my output. But doing it for all the possible combinations is not optimized. I was looking for any other alternative that is possible

My code for the same

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) table1,
COUNT(DISTINCT B.id) table2,
COUNT(DISTINCT C.id) table3,
COUNT(DISTINCT D.id) table4
FROM table1 A
LEFT JOIN table2 B
ON A.id = B.id

LEFT JOIN table3 C
ON A.id = C.id

LEFT JOIN table4 D
ON A.id = D.id
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8N82wMEQpLvBgA1yvqPFRp/0) (This fiddle is for mysql, I am looking for a generic SQL based approach than any db specific approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
with t as (
      select 'table1' as which, id from table1 union all
      select 'table2' as which, id from table2 union all
      select 'table3' as which, id from table3 union all
      select 'table4' as which, id from table4
     )
select ta.which,
       sum(case when tb.which = 'table1' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_table1,
       sum(case when tb.which = 'table2' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_table2,
       sum(case when tb.which = 'table3' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_table3,
       sum(case when tb.which = 'table4' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_table4
from t ta left join
     t tb
     on ta.id = tb.id
group by ta.which;
```

Note:  This assumes that `id` is unique in each of the tables.  That is a reasonable assumption given the name of the column and the sample data.  However, if there are duplicates, you can change the `union all` in the CTE to `union`.

This structure also readily generalizes to additional tables.

Comment: This is the kind of answer/code I was looking for. This looks much cleaner, intelligent and have reduced the code length significantly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ec33de7de4b10eaec9f231a43111b41)**

```
select 'table1' as col1,count(table1.id),count(table2.id),count(table3.id),count(table4.id) 
from table1
left join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
left join table3 on table1.id=table3.id
left join table4 on table1.id=table4.id
union all
select 'table2' ,count(table1.id),count(table2.id),count(table3.id),count(table4.id) 
from table2
left join table1 on table2.id=table1.id
left join table3 on table2.id=table3.id
left join table4 on table2.id=table4.id
union all
select 'table3' ,count(table1.id),count(table2.id),count(table3.id),count(table4.id) 
from table3
left join table1 on table3.id=table1.id
left join table2 on table3.id=table2.id
left join table4 on table3.id=table4.id
union all
select 'table4' ,count(table1.id),count(table2.id),count(table3.id),count(table4.id) 
from table4
left join table1 on table4.id=table1.id
left join table2 on table4.id=table2.id
left join table3 on table4.id=table3.id
```

OUTPUT:

```
col1    tbl1    tbl2    tbl3    tbl4
table1   8      3        2       2
table2   3      6        1       0
table3   2      1        5       0
table4   2      0        0       4
```

Comment: I will have to still write the code 4 times for 4 tables. I reality I have > 20 such tables. I was looking for an approach that will reduce the code length. I have upvoted the answer for your effort